# Splitting the color of a curved text along a path in svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm using SVG in HTML to draw a bended word along a path. Now that I managed to do draw the text, I need to split the word in 2 colors along the path that the word sits on. You can see the effect I'm trying to make in the image. Does anyone know how can I split the word in such a way? (I'm not sure if this matters, but the word is constantly bended, stretched and moved by the user, by modifying the "d" attribute of the path.)[image]

```js
var path = document.getElementById("Path");
var textPath = document.getElementById("TextPath");
document.onmousemove = function(e){
    path.setAttribute("d", `M 100 100 q ${e.x-100} ${e.y-100} 230 0`);
    textPath.setAttribute("textLength", path.getTotalLength() + "px")
}
```

```css
svg {
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<svg>
    <path id="Path" d="M 100 100 q 50 -100 230 0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" fill="none"></path>
    <text id="Text" fill="#000000" font-size="64px">
        <textPath startOffset="0%" id="TextPath" alignment-baseline="middle" href="#Path" startOffset="0%" startOffset="0%">Example</textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

Here's a simpler version of what I have now. What I want to happen, is to color everything above the curve with one color and everything below with another.

Comment: You need to provide some code if you want some help

Comment: Define a `linearGradient` with only two colors and use it as `fill`. Search online for 'svg fill linear gradient'.

Comment: It's not totally clear what you want - I can see how the split is defined when you have only two colors, but can't extrapolate that to more colors. Could you explain more? Also it would really help if you could provide a runnable snippet see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing it: you use the text twice: once filled with color A and once filled with color B. Next you clip the second text with the path.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 260 200">
  <defs>
    <path id="pth" d="M70,150 C10,40 240,40 180,150" stroke="red" fill="none" />
    <text id="txt" font-size="45" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">
      <textPath font-size="35" startOffset="50%" href="#pth">
        SSSSSSSSSSSS
      </textPath>
    </text>
    <clipPath id="cp">
      <use href="#pth" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>

  <use href="#txt" fill="blue" />
  <use href="#txt" fill="orange" clip-path="url(#cp)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect! I've been trying for a week to get this to work.